# Как изменить цвет шкалы диспетчера задач на зеленый windows 10

Tags: windows-10, диспетчер-задач

То есть значок диспетчера задач в трее синий, а я хочу зеленый.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Берете и отслеживаете что запущен Task Manager, и просто перехватываете и поверх этого значка рисуете свой, иначе никак

Comment: @sepera_okeq, Как это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Установил "Classic Task Manager". Задача решена.